# Group by on range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I've read some topics about group by sequence but I could not figure out an solution for my problem.

I have a table (the name is `ViewHistory`) like this.

```
Tme                         Value
2020-07-22 09:30:00         1
2020-07-22 09:31:00         2
2020-07-22 09:32:00         3
2020-07-22 09:33:00         4
2020-07-22 09:34:00         5
2020-07-22 09:35:00         6
.
.
.
```

The data can grow indefinitely.

In this table, there are many records with `1 min` TimeFrame.

I want to group on range of dataTime with timeFrame `2 min` and `Sum(value)`.
like this output:

```
TimeFrame   SumData
09:30       1
09:32       5 -- sum of range 09:31_09:32
09:34       9 -- sum of range 09:33_09:34
.
.
.
```

How can I do this automatically, instead of using a:

`WHERE Tme BETWEEN ('2020-07-22 09:31:00' AND '2020-07-22 09:32:00')` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is a simpler way, but its not coming to me right now.

```
declare @Test table (tme datetime2, [value] int)

insert into @Test (tme, [value])
values
('2020-07-22 09:30:00',         1),
('2020-07-22 09:31:00',         2),
('2020-07-22 09:32:00',         3),
('2020-07-22 09:33:00',         4),
('2020-07-22 09:34:00',         5),
('2020-07-22 09:35:00',         6);

with cte as (
  select convert(date, tme) [date], datepart(hour, tme) [hour], datepart(minute,dateadd(minute, 1,tme)) / 2 [minute], sum([value]) [value]
  from @Test
  group by convert(date, tme), datepart(hour, tme), datepart(minute,dateadd(minute, 1,tme)) / 2
)
select convert(varchar(2),[hour]) + ':' + convert(varchar(2), [minute] * 2) [time], [value]
  -- , dateadd(minute, [minute] * 2, dateadd(hour, [hour], convert(datetime2, [date]))) -- Entire date if desired
from cte;
```

Which gives:

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 9:30 | 1 |
| 9:32 | 5 |
| 9:34 | 9 |
| 9:36 | 6 |

Comment: thx @Dale K, it's seem very close to answer, please check the your result with my output.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` the calculation so you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: @Charlieface could do - feels like over egging the pudding in this case.